# Algorithm for counting substrings in a numerical range

Tags: algorithm, numbers, substring

I'm looking for a fast algorithm that can be used to solve this problem: Giving A and B integers (in the range [0,10^18]), and giving a list of N (N<=1000) numerical substrings; the goal is to count all the numbers in the range [A,B] containing any of the N substrings. We've always A<=B and the numerical substrings are also integers in the range [0,10^18].

Example1: if A=10, B=22, and giving N=2 substrings={1,10} ; the count would be = 11; counting the numbers: 10->19 and 21.

Example2: If A=175, B=201, and giving N=3 substrings={55,0,200} ; the count would be = 4; counting the numbers: 180, 190, 200 and 201.

The straight-forward way is to analyse each integer in the range [A,B], one after another, but it's not a solution since the range can be so big (until 10^18 integers).

One first thing I did to reduce the problem complexity is to delete some useless substrings from the original list of N substrings, such that "no substring is contained in another". For example: {1,10} becomes {1} and {55,0,200} becomes {55,0}. This won't change the final count.

Next, even assuming we can get the count for one substring in the range [A,B], we still cannot sum this count with those of other substrings from the list, as one number can contain many substrings and should not be counted more than once.

Any ideas to solve the problem et get the wanted count?

Comment: +1 for deleting useless sub-strings

Comment: Is there a time limit for this problem?

Comment: @vbmaster, this was a problem in an ACM programming contest, and usually a time limit of few seconds ... but actually for me, even a correct solution in minutes is desired ...

Comment: The answer below is almost correct, and to be clearer, you basically need to apply [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for many times.

Comment: There's an algorithm along the lines of (i) construct a DFA that recognizes strings having one of the N as a substring (ii) use dynamic programming to count the number of matched strings.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, can you provide more details on the DFA?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more of a combinatorial problem.

1. Calculate the possible number of digits of numbers between A and B. For example between 2 and 2000, the number of digits can be 1, 2, 3 or 4. With 1 digit, you need to calculate for numbers > 2 and for 4 digits, you have to calculate the numbers less than 2000, i.e, beginning with 1.
2. If the number of digits is k, and you have to say find the numbers containing substring 234, then choose where you will place that substring (in k-2 ways) and then find the number of permutations for all the possible remaining digits (i think in 10 ^ (k-3) ways). Ofcourse you will have to discount for leading zeroes etc.
3. Repeat this for all substrings.
4. Now you will have to subtract the ones that contain more than one substrings. Repeat the above procedure for all combinations of substrings and subtract it from the calculated value.

Comment: But... this method is not fast enough, especially step 4... "Repeat the above procedure for all combinations of substrings", that is a big number

Comment: Yes but with maximum 18 digits, there should not be many substrings that can possibly co-exist in a number. In fact after removal of useless substrings, i think at max 18 substrings can possibly coexist.

Comment: What about, for example, 1000 to 1999? I don't think any of them can be deleted, and at least we need to do these steps for C(1000,4) times, which is still a large number.

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm sure the above method needs and can be  improved in terms of efficiency. Edit: actually for the range of substrings you provided, you just need to check for a 1 with 3 digits after it.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, I found no formula for step (2) when we deal with many substrings (needed for subtractions). More precisely: having m substrings, how many numbers of k digits contain them all together?

Comment: As stated by @vbmaster you need to apply the inclusion-exclusion principle multiple times. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle